# Cannot find module bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack

Somewhere in development this error started showing, I can't pinpoint where it comes from. The error is to 'broad' for my knowledge. I'm using webpack and gulp. If anyone can point me in the right direction.

I can post more code, but you'll need to tell me what files. The app works as it should, REST, pages loading, etc.. Only the css is not showing.

```
Starting gatling-rsync-deamon...

Starting containers...
Starting vagrant_redis_1
Starting vagrant_mongo_1
Starting vagrant_app_1
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

 launching stream...
[14:39:00] Requiring external module babel-register
[14:39:14] Using gulpfile /var/www/app/gulpfile.babel.js
[14:39:14] Starting 'set-dev-env'...
NODE_ENV will be set to development...
[14:39:14] Finished 'set-dev-env' after 310 μs
[14:39:14] Starting 'backend-watch'...
[14:39:14] Backend warming up...
[14:39:14] Starting 'frontend-watch'...
[14:39:15] Finished 'frontend-watch' after 694 ms
[14:39:15] Starting 'server'...
[14:39:15] Finished 'server' after 1.55 ms
Webpack-dev-server listening at localhost:9090.

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/app/build/bundle'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
[14:39:20] Finished 'backend-watch' after 5.25 s
[14:39:20] Starting 'dev'...
[14:39:20] Finished 'dev' after 3.46 μs
Hash: 5e15e9e5b2fd1c868120
Version: webpack 1.13.0
```

gulpfile.babel.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gutil from 'gulp-util';
import nodemon from 'nodemon';
import path from 'path';
import jsdoc from 'gulp-jsdoc3';
import WebpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
// import backendConfig from './config/webpack.backend.config.js';
// import frontendConfig from './config/webpack.frontend.config.js';

import configs from './config/webpack.config';
import jsdocConfig from './config/jsdoc.config';

const [frontendConfig, backendConfig] = configs;


const FRONTEND_PORT = 8085;
const BACKEND_PORT = 9090;

function onBuild(err, stats) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  console.log(stats.toString());
}

// Default: list all tasks.
gulp.task('default', () => {
  console.log('Available commands: dev, build');
});

// Start frontend
gulp.task('frontend', (done) => {
  webpack(frontendConfig).run((err, stats) => {
    onBuild(err, stats);
    done();
  });
});

// Start frontend watch
gulp.task('frontend-watch', () => {
  const webpackDevserver = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(frontendConfig), {
    publicPath: frontendConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: { colors: true },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '*': `http://localhost:${BACKEND_PORT}`
    }
  });
  webpackDevserver.listen(BACKEND_PORT, 'localhost', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(`Webpack-dev-server listening at localhost:${BACKEND_PORT}.`);
    }
  });
});

// Start backend
gulp.task('backend', (done) => {
  webpack(backendConfig).run((err, stats) => {
    onBuild(err, stats);
    done();
  });
});

// Start backend watch
gulp.task('backend-watch', (done) => {
  gutil.log('Backend warming up...');
  let firedDone = false;

  webpack(backendConfig).watch(100, (err, stats) => {
    if (!firedDone) { done(); firedDone = true; }
    onBuild(err, stats);
    nodemon.restart();
  });
});

// 
// gulp.task('run', ['set-dev-env', 'backend-watch'], () => {
//   nodemon({
//     execMap: {
//       js: 'node'
//     },
//     script: path.join(__dirname, 'build/backend'),
//     ignore: ['*'],
//     watch: ['foo/'],
//     ext: 'noop'
//   }).on('restart', () => {
//     console.log('Patched!');
//   });
// });

// Set NODE_ENV to development
gulp.task('set-dev-env', () => {
  console.log('NODE_ENV will be set to development...');
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});

// Set NODE_ENV to production
gulp.task('set-prod-env', () => {
  console.log('NODE_ENV will be set to production...');
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});

// Start server
gulp.task('server', () => {
  nodemon({
    execMap: {
      js: 'node'
    },
    script: path.join(__dirname, 'build/bundle'),
    ignore: ['*'],
    watch: ['foo/'],
    ext: 'noop'
  }).on('restart', () => {
    console.log('Server restarted!');
  });
});

// Generate docs
gulp.task('docs', (cb) => {
  // gulp.src(['README.md', './client/**/*.js', './server/**/*.js'], { read: false })
  //       .pipe(jsdoc(jsdocConfig, cb));
});

// Build project
gulp.task('build', ['set-prod-env', 'build-js']);

// Build backend & frontend
gulp.task('build-js', ['backend', 'frontend']);

// Watch backend & frontend
gulp.task('watch', ['backend-watch', 'frontend-watch']);

// Start development session
gulp.task('dev', ['set-dev-env', 'backend-watch', 'frontend-watch', 'server']);
```

webpack.config

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
const embedFileSize = 50000;

const nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(module => {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(module) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(mod => {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

const frontendConfig = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.js')
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'public')
  },

  devtool: 'sourcemap',

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './client/public/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': 'es6-promise',
      'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      '__DEV__': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],

  module: {
    preloaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'eslint'}
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json?$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      },
      { test: /\.svg/,
        loader: 'url?limit=' + embedFileSize + '&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      },
      { test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=' + embedFileSize + '&mimetype=image/png'
      },
      { test: /\.jpg/,
        loader: 'url?limit=' + embedFileSize + '&mimetype=image/jpeg'
      },
      { test: /\.gif/,
        loader: 'url?limit=' + embedFileSize + '&mimetype=image/gif'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=' + embedFileSize
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css']
  },
};

const serverConfig = {
  entry: './server/server.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  devtool: 'sourcemap',

  target: 'node',
  // do not include polyfills or mocks for node stuff
  node: {
    console: false,
    global: false,
    process: false,
    Buffer: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false
  },
  externals: nodeModules,

  plugins: [
    // enable source-map-support by installing at the head of every chunk
    new webpack.BannerPlugin('require("source-map-support").install();',
      {raw: true, entryOnly: false})
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        // transpile all .js files using babel
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};

export default [frontendConfig, serverConfig];
```

Comment: Please show gulpfile.js and gulpfile.babel.js code

Comment: @KrzysztofSztompka Thanks for taking interest. Updated.

Comment: please show also ./config/webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

My answer for now is based on your pasted code. When I get more info, then I will edit this answer.

Im not sure If I can find remotely correct solution for you. But your problem is probably with public path which is added to webpack and to WebpackDevServer. WebpackDevServer doesn't see your js code which is bundled in bundle.js

Comment: Can't recall changing something in eiher of the 2 files, weird. I've updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your target to "web" instead of node. You should compile for a web type of environment most likely and not a node.js like environment.

```
target: 'web',
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module "fs" at webpackMissingModule.

Comment: Already did. fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
   ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'readdirSync'

Comment: My original error sttill stands btw. I think this is not the right path to follow.

Comment: Hmm, I have to apologize, I remember getting the same issue and these solutions I had offered fixed it for me. Also I have tried exactly what you have there for "fs.readdirSync('node_modules')" which removes duplicate node modules. I completely stripped this off my last webpack build and everything worked fine. I know it makes your build process faster if you do this but it was causing so much issues for me when I did this technique.